# Как расположить один блок под другим с использованием псевдо-элементов

Tags: css, позиционирование, z-index

Почему не работает z-index у псевдо-элемента :after? Нужно чтобы красный блок перекрывал зеленый

https://codepen.io/AlikinVV/pen/dVXzoa

```
.test {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
display: block;
background: red;
position: relative;
z-index: 2;
margin-left: 40px;
margin-top: 40px;
transform: rotate(45deg);
&::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    right: -10px;
    bottom: -10px;
    background: green;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

}

РЕШЕНИЕ:

https://codepen.io/AlikinVV/pen/ZXOJwM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделать так, как вы хотите, нельзя. У вас родитель div с классом "test" имеет z-index:2 и все вложенные в него элементы будут иметь минимум z-index:2 и не могут быть ниже родителя.
В вашем примере псевдоэлемент 
:after можно заменить на

```
box-shadow: 10px 10px green;
```

и получится то, что вы хотите.